# Cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am trying to convert .net core 2.0 web app to .net core 3.1

I followed all the steps but am stuck on the below issue where I get this build error:
cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment'

Below is my code:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
     app.UseSecurityHeaders(Configuration, env)
           .UseWsFedAuth(Configuration)
           .UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
       Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "app")),
            RequestPath = "/app"
        });

}
```

I am getting the error on line  app.UseSecurityHeaders(Configuration, env)

I have also added below namespace

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
```

Please provide inputs to fix the issue Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, it looks that the `UseSecurityHeaders` constructor method need to use the `IHostingEnvironment` parameter.

To solve this issue, you could try to change the `IWebHostEnvironment` to `IHostingEnvironment`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
     app.UseSecurityHeaders(Configuration, env)
           .UseWsFedAuth(Configuration)
           .UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
       Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "app")),
            RequestPath = "/app"
        });

}
```

Besides, if the `UseSecurityHeaders()` is in the third party package, you could check the package version and try to upgrade it, the updated(recent) version package might be use the `IWebHostEnvironment` interface.